# Why do my variable values change when running two or more sessions?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have written a shell script that is executed by a scheduler to run multiple jobs at the same time; it may have three or more session executed at the same time.

When I check the zip file, I can see a mismatch; for example, if I pass `dir=A` and  `file =A_file` in the first session, and in another session I pass `dir=B` and `file=B_file`, I can see `dir=A` has the file `B_file`.

I can't use FLOCK as I need to run in parallel without affecting performance.

Is there any way to run the `mv` and `zip` commands only after they have completed in other sessions, or any other solution for this?

```sh
dir = $1
filepath=$2
mkdir $dir
mv $filepath $dir
zip -r zipfilename.zip $dir
```

Comment: It's not clear how you actually run the script. Separate instances shouldn't be able to see each other's variables.

Comment: it is running on same server

Comment: `dir = $1` do you really mean `dir=$1`?